# docker /bin/sh: 1: .: Can't open /path

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have an sbt project `projectA` under `home/demo/projectA`  my `Dockerfile` resides in `/home/demo/` for some reason i don't want it to be inside `projectA`
so hierarchy looks like this

home/demo

- Dockerfile
- projectA

here i am trying to run `sbt` command in the image build process here is the contents of my Dockerfile

```
FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.2_2.12.8_1.2.8 as stripecommon

MAINTAINER sara <sarawaheed3191@gmail.com>

WORKDIR /aa


RUN \
  . /home/demo/projectA sbt
```

I am getting this error when building the image

```
:~/home/demo$ docker build -t testapp .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.297GB
Step 1/4 : FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.2_2.12.8_1.2.8 as stripecommon
 ---> 349a7e4f4029
Step 2/4 : MAINTAINER sara <sarawaheed3191@gmail.com>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8603662d3730
Step 3/4 : WORKDIR /aa
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f07ec5bb4d34
Step 4/4 : RUN   . /home/demo/projectA sbt
 ---> Running in 7509ee45f622
/bin/sh: 1: .: Can't open /home/demo/projectA
The command '/bin/sh -c . /home/demo/projectA sbt' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

what is the right way to do this also i am a beginner in docker help will be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker GO build returned a non-zero code: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371508/docker-go-build-returned-a-non-zero-code-1)

Comment: I don't understand this line `RUN   . /home/demo/projectA sbt`. Why don't execute directly `RUN /home/demo/projectA sbt`. I suppose projectA is the binary and sbt the argument, isn't it?

Comment: it says /bin/sh: 1: /home/demo/projectA: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c /home/demo/projectA sbt.' returned a non-zero code: 127
here projectA is an sbt project and 'sbt' is the command i am giving as a argument

Comment: Where do you create `/home/demo/projectA` inside your image?

Comment: i did not i just created a workdir of aa

Comment: looks like you forgot to add `COPY ./projectA /home/demo/`. just add this line before the `RUN` command in the dockerfile

Comment: Cross posting to multiple SE sites is discouraged. Please find the most appropriate site for your question and post there. Ref: https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/8131/7730

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that projectA exists inside the container. so for this either you pick code from github or copy it using COPY or ADD command. After that you can build it using sbt.